# Using class variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

Beginner here, learning ruby on rails by jumping into a project. This question is probably pure ruby and has nothing to do with rails. I also want to note that I'm using Active_Admin.

I have the following 2 classes: Owner and Phone.

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password,
  has_many :phones
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :owner_id :model
  belongs_to :owner
end
```

How would I go accessing the owners email from within the phones model, for example:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Phone Details" do
    f.input :model
    f.input :owner_id   # This is where I want the email, not the owners id.
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

It looks like I should review the pickaxe book and refine my ruby before jumping into rails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to have both the owner and the phone in one form, your form should look something like this:

```
form_for @phone do |phone_form|
  phone_form.label :model
  phone_form.text_field :model
  fields_for @phone.owner do |owner_fields|
    owner_fields.label :email
    owner_fields.text_field :email
```

If you use this method, make sure you can update the `Owner` from the `Phone` model by setting [`accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) on you `Phone` model.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use `nested form`. Usage of nested form is explained very well in [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) railscast.